# Getting Twitter usernames in Python

Tags: python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to read tweets for the following keywords on Twitter (cycling, running, sports suck) and would also like to get the **username** of the person who sent the Tweet.  I've scoured the web, but haven't come up with an answer that seems to work.  I don't think I understand exactly what it is I'm looking for?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, my code so far is below...

Thanks

```
import tweepy
from time import sleep 
import sys
non_bmp_map = dict.fromkeys(range(0x10000, sys.maxunicode + 1), 0xfffd)

CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxx'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'xxxx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
auth.secure = True
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        if 'cycling' in status.text.lower():
                print('BIKE!')
                print(status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))
        elif 'running' in status.text.lower():
            print('RUN!')
            print(status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))
        else:
            print('SPORTS SUCK!')
            print(status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth = api.auth, listener=myStreamListener())

myStream.filter(track=['cycling', 'running', 'sports suck'])
```

I've added this code... (the lines with # in).  It keeps coming up with an error message: *TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable* Any ideas?

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
def on_status(self, status):
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor: #I'VE ADDED THIS LINE
        if 'cycling' in status.text.lower():
                print('BIKE!')
                print(status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))
                print(tweet.user.screen_name) #I'VE ADDED THIS LINE
        elif 'running' in status.text.lower():
            print('RUN!')
            print(status.text.translate(non_bmp_map))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely look into [this Python API](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) that allows to receive the tweet sent and the username of the sender. I had no experience with python and I made it work really fast and easy.

All useful source code & way of getting it to work is on the git page :-)